# When does/doesn't the sequence from Euler's method exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

For a differential equation say $y'=ty^3$ with $y(0)=1$ how would we know if the sequence from Euler's method exists or not?

So I know this particular equation has solution:

$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

So hence has a discontinuity at $t=1$. So does the sequence from Euler's method exist for all $n$? How could I find out? Any hints would be great!

Comment: You will get floating-point overflow at some point. In practical terms, you would need to define a range-of-interest for $y$ and check if the numerical values leave that range.

Comment: @LutzLehmann could you expand further on floating point overflow?

Comment: Your solution will grow above all bounds. While you will not get a singularity at $t=1$, you get at least a growth that has $y_h(t+1)\ge y_h(t)^3$. The available range of floating point numbers gets used up quickly with such a dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler method for this example reads as
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+ht_ny_n^3.
$$
According to the nature of the ODE, consider $y_n^{-2}$. Then the iteration is approximately
$$
y_{n+1}^{-2}=y_n^{-2}(1+ht_ny_n^2)^{-2}
=y_n^{-2}(1-2ht_ny_n^2+3h^2t_n^2y_n^4+O(h^3))
\approx y_n^{-2}-2ht_n,
$$
as long as $hy_n^2$ remains small, $y_n^{-2}\gg h$. As $t_n=nh$ this can be solved as
$$
y_n^{-2}\approx y_0^{-2}-n(n-1)h^2=y_0^{-2}-t_n(t_n-h).
$$
This means that at $t_n\approx 1$, $n=\lfloor\frac1h\rfloor$, the Euler iteration will reach a value $y_n\approx\frac1{\sqrt h}$, and thus $y_{n+1}\approx\frac2{\sqrt h}$, and from that moment on the second term will dominate,
$$
\sqrt{h}y_{n+k+1}\ge(\sqrt{h}y_{n+k})^3\implies y_{n+k}\ge\frac1{\sqrt{h}}2^{3^{k-1}},~~ k\ge 1
$$
Normal 64bit floating point numbers go up to $2^{1024}$, that range gets exceeded before $k=7$.

While in theory the Euler sequence can be indefinitely prolonged, in praxis there is no computer that can do this, the (observable, estimated) universe gets exhausted before $k=200$.